# how to upload multipe images ,in django rest framework(drf)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to upload multiple images,A picture is just a property in the model.The image information I want to get when I send a GET request is a list of urls.

The images is just a attribute in my model.

model.py

```
class sellGoods(models.Model):

    img = models.ImageField(max_length=100, upload_to=get_file_path, default='sell.png', verbose_name='图片',
                            null=True, blank=True)
    # 与用户绑定
    # user = models.ForeignKey(UserInfo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    goods_name = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('物品名称'), max_length=90)
    # Many attributes are omitted here
```

serializers.py
`

```
class sellSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    

    class Meta:
        model = sellGoods
        fields = '__all__'
```

`

view.py

```
class sellGoodsList(APIView):
    

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = sellSerializer(data=request.data)
        qdata = request.data
        print('1: ',qdata)
        print('2: ',qdata['img'])
        print('3: ',qdata.get('img'))

        print('------------')
        if serializer.is_valid():

            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

in postman

[image]

[image]

Realize uploading multiple image

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to add additional attributes for each image?

Comment: I wonder if the image can be used as a property in MM instead of a foreign key to enable multiple image uploads